# how the cube will stand on the floor in a parcur game

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can you help with the code?
I'm creating a parkour game and everything went well but I got stuck on it:
as the cube will stand on the floor.
Here is my js code:

```
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      //Налаштування


      var width = canvas.width;
      var height = canvas.height;


      var gameOver = function () {
         clearInterval(intervalId);
         ctx.font = "60px Caurier";
         ctx.textAlign = "cener";
         ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
         ctxfillText("GAME OVER", width / 2, height / 2);
      };


      var cicle = function (x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
         if (fillCircle) {
            ctx.fill();
         } else {
            ctx.stroke();
         }
      };


      //Людина
      //намалювати
      function Draw() {
         this.x = 10;
         this.y = 10;

      }
      Draw.prototype.draw = function () {
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
         ctx.lineTo(this.x + 50, this.y);
         ctx.lineTo(this.x + 50, this.y + 50);
         ctx.lineTo(this.x, this.y + 50);
         ctx.lineTo(this.x, this.y);
         ctx.fill();
      }
      Draw.prototype.move = function () {
         if (this.x < 0) {
            this.x = 0;
         } else if (this.x > 1250) {
            this.x = 1250;
         }
         if (this.y < 0) {
            this.y = 0;
         } else if (this.y > 450) {
            this.y = 450;
         }

         while (this.y < 450) {
            this.y++;
         }
      }
      Draw.prototype.setDirection = function (direction) {
         if (direction === "left") {
            this.x = this.x - 10;
         } else if (direction === "right") {
            this.x = this.x + 10;
         } else if (direction === "up") {
            this.y = this.y - 150;
         }
      }
      var person = new Draw;

      var keyActions = {
         37: "left",
         38: "up",
         39: "right"
      };
      $("body").keydown(function (event) {
         var direction = keyActions[event.keyCode];
         person.setDirection(direction);
      });

      setInterval(function () {
         ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1300, 500);
         person.draw();
         person.move();
         //карта
         var floor = ctx.strokeStyle = "LimeGreen"; ctx.lineWidth = 4; ctx.strokeRect(0, 312, 1300, 362);
      }, 30);
```

I tried a lot but it didn't work out.
For example, I tried this:
first the code checks whether the cube and the floor are in the same coordinates, if so it reflects, if not, then no.I want the cube to be able to walk on the floor which is painted green, and not pass through it.

Comment: Could you describe more what you want happen to the cube.

Comment: I want the cube to be able to walk on the floor which is painted green, and not pass through it.